# what is way to work out $_POST in array from submit in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, post

I have the following post from a form:

```
array(3) { ["product"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "793" [1]=> string(3) "783" }
["qty"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } 
["price"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "24.50" [1]=> string(5) "55.00" }}
```

which comes as information needed to send order. What is the best way loop within post so I can get:

> Product 793 - qty 1 - price -24.50
>   Product 783 - qty 1 - price
>   -55.00

do I need to loop :

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $product){
$pid = $product;   
}
```

for each post or there is other solution? 
Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with looping as suggested?

Comment: isnt it possible to get the row information with 1 loop instead of looping each post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product']); $i++) {
    $product = $_POST['product'][$i];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
    echo "Product $product - qty $qty - price -$price";
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what i need Tony - Thanks ! Accepted as answer!

Comment: No, you just upvoted it. you have to click on the green check on the left to accept the answer

Comment: I now, Alex, but must wait 3 minutes :)